# More performant 2D raytracing than Radiosity?

Tags: lighting, raytracing

Currently if you want real-time 2D ray-traced scene lighting, you're limited to a few options: geometry based SDFs or Scene Based Radiosity. However 2D Radiosity is really the only choice if your game doesn't conform to geometric shapes.

Here's the general idea behind radiosity: (https://github.com/FatalSleep/2DGI see example/blog I've written in GameMaker or GODOT tutorial with article https://samuelbigos.github.io/posts/2dgi1-2d-global-illumination-in-godot.html)

1. Generate a Scene Texture with all light-collidable objects (walls, characters, etc.).
2. Compute the JFA of the Scene Texture.
3. Compute the SDF of the Scene Texture using the JFA.
4. Compute Noise Texture or use a pre-computed noise-texture (recommended Blue-Noise).
5. Radiosity Fragment Shader:

   1. For each pixel cast N-rays in every direction.
   2. SDF march across the Scene Texture until out-of-bounds or hit on scene SDF.
   3. Return scene texture color at the end of the ray (along with pixel at edge of surface).
   4. Compute the emissive surface color and apply tonemapping.
6. Pass the scene back into itself on the next pass to "spread light," across the scene. This is a critical step of actually having smooth-edged shadows, because you want to seed the light scene with the previous output so that ray-checks can get both the surface color of the scene, plus any adjacent lighting that was computed prior.

2D Radiosity is great and all, but performantly very weak, even on an RTX 3080 with a full 1080p scene, you wouldn't hit 120 FPS with complex scenes (depending on the number of rays-per-pixel, which needs to be higher for larger scenes).

With that out of the way, is there any possible way to modify this approach or do something entirely different using AMD and NVidia's hardware accelerated RT cores?

One potential contender I found is this, although closed-source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20DXERpj4rg

Description by the developer:

> Think of the 2d grid as a heightmap, where each pixel stores a height/layer offset. As an example to achieve shadows, you start at a given pixel and shoot a ray towards the light source. For every pixel the ray intersects with, take it's height and compare it with the height of the pixel you've started from. If the height of the intersected pixel is larger than the height of the source pixel, you're in shadow. This idea can be extended to global illumination, reflections etc.